# Multiple spawned objects on collision - Corona SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, physics, collision, coronasdk

Please help! I'm trying to spawn 5 balls one by one from the sky and have them disappear as soon as they hit the ground or when they hit another user-controlled object that's on the ground. The good thing is that I can spawn the balls successfully as intended, but when they hit the ground (or the other user-controlled object on the ground), they don't disappear. I've been going through a ton of sample code since the past 2 days but I can't figure out how to do it. The game does run, but the debug terminal gives me an error saying: runtime error - attempt to index global 'self' . Here's the source code:

```
local randomBall = function()
    ball = display.newImage( "hardball.png" )
    ball.x = math.random (30, 450); ball.y = -20
    physics.addBody( ball, { density=2.9, friction=0.5, bounce=0.7, radius=24 } )
    local function whenHit (event)
        if(event.phase == "began") then
            self:removeSelf()       
        end
    end
    ball:addEventListener("collision", whenHit)
end

timer.performWithDelay( 500, randomBall, 5 )
```

Comment: cross-posted here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/16153/9338

Answer (score 0):

Telling us what line that error was on would have been nice, but I can see your problem is in the function whenHit()

It refers to a variable 'self' only you never define that variable. Presumably you want that function to act as a method of 'ball' so the function declaration should use the colon syntax and look something like ball:collision(event)

---

Note that Corona has two ways of setting event listeners. It's explained here in their documentation: http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/events-and-listeners

And then this page in their documentation explains how that applies to collision events:
http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection

It looks like what you are trying to do is a table listener on the ball, in which case your call to addEventListener should be ball:addEventListener("collision", ball) and then the function is ball:collision(event)

The other method they describe is a global listener function and then use event.object1 inside the function to refer to the object that collided.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, I apologize for not mentioning the line number. The terminal shows that the error is in self:removeSelf();
The 5 balls are being spawned by the randomBall function only, so I'm still unable to figure out what the problem is. Would it be possible for you to post some code or an example here for me please?

Comment: It seems like the problem lies within the randomBall function itself. If I place the ball:addEventListener("collision", whenHit) outside the randomBall function and attempt to remove each ball as soon as it hits the ground in a new function called whenHit, terminal shows me that "ball" is a nil value, and again the ball doesn't disappear. Please help

Comment: "ball" is defined inside the randomBall() function so any references to "ball" (such as a call to ball:addEventListener) also need to be inside randomBall(). I'm not sure why you thought it would help to put that outside. And I'm not sure why you thought the problem was with the randomBall() function; I already said the problem was with whenHit(). Specifically, the line with the error is inside whenHit()

Comment: I posted links to the relevant pages in the Corona documentation because you seem rather confused.

Comment: It looks like when multiple physics objects of the same kind are created within a single function, they cannot be destroyed from within the same function, perhaps because the system recognizes each of the objects as the same one. I implemented some of the code from: http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection#Local_collision_listeners
What happens now is, when I test it by doing this:
if (event.phase == "began") then
print("The ball has collided now")

Comment: It DOES show me that the object HAS collided. But when I replace the print command with object.removeSelf() or object.isVisible = false, other balls start disappearing instead of the ones that are colliding with the ground. So it is partially working, perhaps I'm making a very small mistake?
(This comment is a continuation of the previous one. Sorry but my comment exceeded the max number of characters, so I had to split it into 2 comments).

Answer (score 0):

How to spawn objects the right way: https://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/09/14/how-to-spawn-objects-the-right-way/